# Can't access child element in UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I created a UserControl with a TextBlock in it and the problem is I am not able to change the text of this UserControl from the MainPage where I have used this Usercontrol.

Plz help am new to Metro style App basically windows phone developer. Check the source of usercontrol below.

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Version1forMainMenu.MyUserControl1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Version1forMainMenu"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400" x:Name="MyUserControl1">

<Grid x:Name="grid_amorti"  PointerEntered="gride_quickestimate_PointerEntered" PointerExited="gride_quickestimate_PointerExited" PointerPressed="gride_quickestimate_PointerPressed" PointerReleased="gride_quickestimate_PointerReleased" Tapped="gride_quickestimate_Tapped">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Image/inside_menu_normal.png"/>            
    </Grid.Background>


    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  x:Name="edit"   Text="" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Margin="10,112,29,111" ></TextBlock>
    <Image Grid.Row="1" x:Name="img" Grid.Column="5" Source="Image/small_arrow.png"  />


</Grid>
```

I am not able to access the textblock named "edit" from a page where this UserControl is used.

Comment: Why not use [x:FieldModifier Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970905.aspx)?

Comment: That would not be very clean, the names of controls isn't something external elements should know about. The best way IMO is to expose the useful properties, just like a normal control would do. Plus it allows you to databind these properties when you declare and use the UserControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal, the TextBlock is a private field inside the UserControl. You need to re-expose the properties you want to be able to modify, for example with this technique: http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-expose-properties-of-a-user-control-in-windows-phone

Answer (score 0):

It is totally normal as your controls in the usercontrol aren't publicly accessible. You should defin a public property in your usercontrol to make those controls available...

Comment: How to define public property for a control created in XAML.

Comment: @GY1 That's a very good question I'm unfortunately not able to answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing your `Grid.ColumnDefinition`s and `Grid.RowDefinition`s

```
<Grid x:Name="grid_amorti" ...>  
    <Grid.Background>
         <ImageBrush ImageSource="Image/inside_menu_normal.png"/>            
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.ColumnDefintion>

    </Grid.ColumnDefinition>
    <Grid.RowDefiniton>

    </Grid.RowDefinition>
</Grid>
```

So you are actually misplacing them...